# What's the proper way to mock Rails 3 routes and controllers in a plugin test?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, routes, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have an old pre-Rails 3 plugin whose tests will no longer run under Rails 3. The test looks something like this:

```
class TestController < ActionController::Base
  def test_action; render :nothing => true; end
end

TestController.view_paths = [File.dirname(__FILE__)]

ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw {|m| m.connect ':controller/:action/:id' }

class TestControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context "test_action" do
    should "do something" do
      lambda { post :test_action }.should change { Model.count }
    end
  end
end
```

Running this test gets me:

> uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Routing::Routes (NameError)

When I use with_routing, which I *thought* was the new way of doing test routing, like so:

```
should "do something" do
  with_routing do |set|
    set.draw { |m| m.connect ':controller/:action/:id' }
    lambda { post :test_action }.should change { Model.count }
  end
end
```

I get:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `_routes' for TestController:Class

What am I missing? My test helper requires:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require 'active_record/version'
require 'active_record/fixtures'
require 'action_controller'
require 'action_dispatch'
require 'action_view'
require 'test/unit'
require 'shoulda'
require 'mocha'
```

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to draw the routes on Rails.application

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Fun times
end
```

Comment: For the record: this approach will rewrite all app's routes. So be careful there!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Uh, sorry, this won't work on rails 3, but maybe you upgraded already?

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-6/docs/controller-specs/engine-routes-for-controllers

You didn't specify any test framework, so I'll just mention that RSpec gives you `routes` method in `type: :controller` and `type: :routing` specs so you could do something like

```
before do
  routes.draw do
    get  ':controller/:action/:id' => 'controller#action' 
  end
end
```